# activating a delete button after being created in jquery

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to activate a delete button I created using jQuery

I have tried moving the code inside and out of the `$(document).text();`
I have tried targeting a class on the created button
I am not even getting an error from in my console.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var day = '';
var time = '';
var task = '';

$(document).text(function() {
  $("#saveButton").on("click", function() {
    //Save day, time & task to footer.
    day = $("#day").val();
    time = $("#time").val();
    task = $("#task").val();
    $("#inputData").append("<li>" + day +
      " | " + time + " | " + task +
      " | " + "<button class='btn btn-success edit'>Edit</button>" +
      " | " + "<button class='btn btn-danger delete'>Delete</button><br>" + "</li>");
  });
});
$(".delete").on("click", function() {
  day = $("#day").empty();
  time = $("#time").empty();
  task = $("#task").empty();
});
```

Comment: I am very confused with your attempted use of `text()` here.  You appear to be trying to use it like a document ready.  You are not returning a string value at the end, which the `text()` method would expect.  Also your use of `****` in the code is a syntax error.

Comment: Can you also show your HTML?

Comment: is it just a miss type "#delete" instead of ".delete"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Should that be `$(document).ready(` ?

Comment: From the duplicate (which has more info) : `$(document).on("click", "button.delete", function() { day = ...`

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you just need to move the $(".delete").on("click", ...) inside the $("#saveButton").on("click", ...) handler (after you append the new elements to  #inputData), otherwise it will fire at page load (when your .delete button does not yest exist).

```js
$("#saveButton").on("click", function () {
    //Save day, time & task to footer.
    day = $("#day").val();
    time = $("#time").val();
    task = $("#task").val();
    // append the buttons to the dom...
    $("#inputData").append("<li>" + day +
        " | " + time + " | " + task +
        " | " + "<button class='btn btn-success edit'>Edit</button>"
        + " | " + "<button class='btn btn-danger delete'>Delete</button><br>" + "</li>");
    // ...then add the click handler to the new button
    $(".delete").on("click", function() {
       day =  $("#day").empty();
        time = $("#time").empty();
        task = $("#task").empty();
    });
});
```

Suggestion: if you don't want to gat lost with this scenario, you can also add your buttons in the beginning, with a CSS class that hides them, then just show them.

Comment: The issue with this approach is you are looking up elements with the delete class, globally.  This will find the previously found elements that already have a binding on them, and create a duplicate binding.  Either the logic should target specifically the one just created, or the logic should use a delegate binding instead.